# Displaying Simulink block link in Matlab GUi

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I need to display a filtered list of Simulink pathname...
Currently I'm using pushbuttons for each path
Is there a way to display in the form of hiperlink using buttondownfcn?

Comment: please show us what you have done so far

Comment: @dlavila     
Currently I am displaying the list of found block in list style using  

set(varargin{3}.listBlk,'min',0,'max',2,'fontsize',10,'string',{str2mat(blkList)});  

And Opening them using pushbutton callback<br/>
function [] = openBlk(varargin)  
choice = get(varargin{3}.listBlk,{'string','val'});  
open_system(regexprep(strtrim(char(choice{1,1}{choice{1,2},1})),'(.+)(?:\\|/)(.*)', '$1'));  
end